# Problem with select input with Mdbootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize, mdbootstrap

I have added this HTML. The problem is that the input appears two times

```
<select class="mdb-select">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>    

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Material Select Initialization
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mdb-select').material_select();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The currently posted code must work fine http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/xpcvLyqe/2/ The problem is somewhere else and not in the posted code

Comment: Do you have two elements with the className `mdb-select`? If so, then the `material_select()` function will operate on all (both?) of them.

Comment: Initializing the element two times will also lead to the duplication like http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/7eLr6m4z/1/

Comment: Look this picture please https://i.ibb.co/Twqjs6Z/sdsd.png